# How to detect IP of connected to Android workstation?

Tags: android, android-wifi, dhcp

I have smartphone with android. On smartphone works WiFi hotspot. A PC workstation connected to this smartphone over WiFi. On the PC works Apache application server. This server responses on port 8080 by HTTP. The server works as is, there is no possibility to install addition pages or services on the PC.

I need in application on smartphone to detect IP of the connected PC for sending requests to the server on this PC.

Is there any ideas how to do it fast? I can send request to every IP in 192.168.0/24 segment, but it's very slow. Maybe I can read ARP table or parse logs of DHCP server?

Comment: As long as your application server advertises its services correctly, you can use NSD: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html.

Comment: You can read /proc/net/arp, but it's a possible concern that the entry might expire if it's not being used.  The DHCP log would be better if you can find access to it.  Service discovery is a great solution - but only if the other end has implemented something compatible, which is by no means a given.